# Removing polygon holes in OpenLayers

Tags: polygon, openlayers, holes

I wrote some code for removal of polygon holes whose area value is under the hardcoded threshold.

```
source_g.getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getPolygons().forEach(function(poly){

    if(!(poly.getLinearRings().length<=1)) 
    {
        poly.getLinearRings().forEach(function(ring){ 
            if(Math.abs(ring.getArea()) < 0.1){ 

               ring.setCoordinates([])
            }
        })
    };
})
```

The idea is to set coordinates of inner `LinearRings` to `[]`, I tried to do that on the whole feature and it disappeared. But for `LinearRings` it's not doing the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The geometry is defined as an array of coordinates, not collections of Polygons and LinearRings, so what is returned by `getPolygons()` and `getLinearRings()` should be treated as clones and you will need to rebuild the geometry from coordinates

```
var geom = source_g.getFeatures()[0].getGeometry();
var geomCoords = [];
geom.getPolygons().forEach(function(poly){
    var polyCoords = [];
    poly.getLinearRings().forEach(function(ring, index){ 
        if(index == 0 || Math.abs(ring.getArea()) >= 0.1){ 
           polyCoords.push(ring.getCoordinates());
        }
    };
    geomCoords.push(polyCoords);
});
geom.setCoordinates(geomCoords);
```